Parallelizing pcolormesh to plot multiple patches onto the same axes
So I have unstructured data due to AMR grid. Each figure has 2 subplots. I am trying to plot the AMR blocks, which can be a lot, onto the same axes. Because it can take quite some time, I was trying to parallelize the plotting so that each process plots a block on the axes. The script runs but unfortunately returns empty axes. I suppose I have to pass the axes to the function, but I am unsure how.
Here is my code which returns empty axes.
import os,sys
import numpy as np
import function_library as fl
from multiprocessing import Pool
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import tqdm
import time as ttime
import pandas
import dask

# x_corner and y_corner have size [numgrid,17]
# var has size [numgrid,16,16]
# numgrid is the number of blocks

for i in range(indxStart,indxEnd+1):

    fig,axs   = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=len(varPlots),figsize=(10,4),layout='constrained', sharey=True)

    def plotVars(igrid):
        # Rho with electron beams
        pcmRho = axs[0].pcolormesh(x_corner[igrid,:],y_corner[igrid,:], (var[igrid,0,:,:]/HMass).T, norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=vLims[0][0],vmax=vLims[0][1]), cmap=cmaps[0], antialiased=False)
        # Electron beams
        pcmlQ = axs[0].pcolormesh(x_corner[igrid,:],y_corner[igrid,:], var[igrid,2,:,:].T, norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=vLims[2][0] ,vmax=vLims[2][1]), cmap=cmaps[2], antialiased=False)
        pcmcQ = axs[0].pcolormesh(x_corner[igrid,:],y_corner[igrid,:], var[igrid,3,:,:].T, norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=vLims[3][0],vmax=vLims[3][1]), cmap=cmaps[3], antialiased=False)

        # v_y
        pcmVy = axs[1].pcolormesh(x_corner[igrid,:], y_corner[igrid,:], var[igrid,1,:,:].T, norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=vLims[1][0],vmax=vLims[1][1]), cmap=cmaps[1], antialiased=False)

    pool = Pool(numProc)
    r = list(tqdm.tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(plotVars,range(numgrid)),total=numgrid))

    # axes and cbar rho 
    axs[0].set_xlim(xMin,xMax)
    axs[0].set_ylim(yMin,yMax)
    axs[0].set_xlabel('x (Mm)',fontsize=20,weight='bold')
    axs[0].set_ylabel('y (Mm)',fontsize=20,weight='bold')
    axs[0].xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=18)
    axs[0].yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=18)
    cbarRho = plt.colorbar(pcmRho,ax=axs[0])
    cbarRho.set_label(label=cbTxts[0],weight='bold',fontsize=15)

    cbarlQ = plt.colorbar(pcmlQ,ax=axs[0])
    #cbarlQ.set_label(label=cbTxts[0],weight='bold',fontsize=15)

    cbarcQ = plt.colorbar(pcmcQ,ax=axs[0])
    #cbarlQ.set_label(label=cbTxts[0],weight='bold',fontsize=15)

    #axes and cbar vy
    axs[1].set_xlim(xMin,xMax)
    axs[1].set_ylim(yMin,yMax)
    axs[1].set_xlabel('x (Mm)',fontsize=20,weight='bold')
    axs[1].set_ylabel('')
    axs[1].xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=18)
    cbarVy=plt.colorbar(pcmVy,ax=axs[1])
    #cbarVy.set_label(label=cbTxts[1],weight='bold',fontsize=15)  

    plt.suptitle('t = '+str(round(float(time),2))+'s',fontsize=20,weight='bold')

    figName = fileBase+str(i).rjust(4,'0')+'.png'
    plt.savefig(pathFig+figName,dpi=500)
    print(pathFig+figName)
    plt.close()



Your question contains no sample data and no information about what you are using to process the data. From your statement about the amount of time is takes, I suspect that you are not using any pool processing or packages suitable for this type of operations. I would highly recommend dask for this. Here is an example with some simple data. Adapt the solution to fit your needs:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import dask.array as da
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar

numgrid = 10
data = {
    'x_corner': [np.random.rand(10, 10) for _ in range(numgrid)],
    'y_corner': [np.random.rand(10, 10) for _ in range(numgrid)],
    'var': [np.random.rand(4, 10, 10) for _ in range(numgrid)],  
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def process_data_dask(grid_data):
    x_corner_dask = da.from_array(grid_data['x_corner'], chunks=(5, 5))
    y_corner_dask = da.from_array(grid_data['y_corner'], chunks=(5, 5))
    var_dask = da.from_array(grid_data['var'], chunks=(4, 5, 5))

    processed_data = {
        'x_corner': x_corner_dask + 0.1,  
        'y_corner': y_corner_dask + 0.1,
        'var': var_dask * 0.9 
    }

    return {
        'x_corner': processed_data['x_corner'].compute(),
        'y_corner': processed_data['y_corner'].compute(),
        'var': [processed_data['var'][i].compute() for i in range(4)]
    }

results = [process_data_dask(row) for index, row in df.iterrows()]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 4), sharey=True)

with ProgressBar():
    for block in results:
        axs[0].pcolormesh(block['x_corner'], block['y_corner'], block['var'][0], cmap='viridis')
        axs[1].pcolormesh(block['x_corner'], block['y_corner'], block['var'][1], cmap='magma')

plt.show()

which gives (in less than 3 seconds):


I have edited the question to show the modules I am loading and explain the shape of my data. x_corner and y_corner are 2D arrays of size [numgrid,17] while var is a 3D array of size [numgrid, 16,16]. numgrid is the number of blocks, typically around 2000
